# How to use Where-object in Show-ListView Expression

Tags: powershell-extensions, powershell

I have a list(list 1- $itemModes) which contains following fields,

```
class Mode {
    [string]$WorkflowName
    [string]$WorkflowId
    [string]$ItemId
    [string]$ItemName
    [string]$InstallMode
    [string]$MergeMode
}
[Mode[]]$itemModes=@()
```

I have another list(list2- $items) as follows,

```
 $items |
        Show-ListView @props -Property @{Label="Name"; Expression={$_.DisplayName} },           
            @{Label="Workflow State"; Expression={(Get-Item -Path "master:" -ID $_."__Workflow state").Name} },
            @{ Name="Source"; Expression={}},
            @{ Name="InstallMode"; Expression={}},
            @{ Name="MergeMode"; Expression={}}
```

How do I update the InstallMode, MergeMode values from list 1 in list 2 I need to match the item Id and workflow name. How do I use where-object with in,

```
@{ Name="InstallMode"; Expression={}},
@{ Name="MergeMode"; Expression={}}
```

Eg:

```
@{ Name="InstallMode"; Expression={$itemModes.InstallMode|Where-Object $_.Id -eq $itemModes.Id -and $_.WorkflowName -eq $itemModes.WorkflowName}},
@{ Name="MergeMode"; Expression={$itemModes.MergeMode|Where-Object $_.Id-eq $itemModes.Id -and $_.WorkflowName -eq $itemModes.WorkflowName}}
```

I am not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this, then you need to first filter using the `Where-Object` and then call `Show-ListView` to show these filtered results. So I am showing a sample code here and then you need to adjust it wherever you want to use it.

```
# Getting the list of items 
$listOfPagesInTree = Get-ChildItem -Path "master:\content\home" -Recurse

# Filtering it using the Where-Object and then showing using Show-ListView
$listOfPagesInTree | Where-Object { $_.TemplateName -eq "Sample Item"} | Show-ListView
```

Hope this will help you to complete your code.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks Sumit! I was able to achieve the desired result.